# React TypeError: onGenreChange is not a function

Tags: reactjs, onclick, event-listener

I'm trying to pass a function to an event listener (onClick), but I get the following error: TypeError: onGenreChange is not a function. I believe I properly passed in a lambda function to the event listener. Does anyone know why this is not working? Thank you!

```
class Genres extends Component {
    render() {

        const { activeGenre, onGenreChange, items, textProperty, valueProperty } = this.props;
        const genres = [];

        for (let n = 0; n < items.length; n++) {
            const genre = items[n][textProperty]
            genres.push(<ListGroup.Item onClick={() => {onGenreChange(genre)}} key={genre[valueProperty]} as="li" active={genre === activeGenre}>{genre}</ListGroup.Item>)
        }

        return (<React.Fragment>
            <ListGroup as="ul">
                <ListGroup.Item onClick={() => onGenreChange("All Genres")} as="li" active={"All Genres" === activeGenre}>All Genres</ListGroup.Item>
                {genres}
            </ListGroup>
        </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, what are you passing to the `Genres` component? `<Genre onGenreChange={?} />`

Comment: Can you post the code where you use this component ?

Comment: Ahh I see, the problem was with the event handler inside of the parent component. OnGenreChange pointed to an invalid function. Thanks!